Are the Psalms actually quite limited in the types of suffering they address, and what does this mean for us?
You will often hear people say things like, "The Psalms cover every human emotion and situation." There's even a John Calvin quote somewhere. And the "covering every emotions" part may be true. But something has bothered me about this type of statement for a while.
Now, I certainly could be missing something, but as I have read the Psalms more lately it seems that it only addresses really two types of suffering: a) Attacks/false accusations from enemies and b) suffering caused by sin/iniquity.
Many Psalms feature the general 'cry of the afflicted' but when the reason is given, it seems to always come down to the two forms I mentioned above. Here's a couple examples:

Psalm 103:3 speaks of "healing our diseases" but there is disagreement from commentators whether this is really referring to the "disease" of sin.

Psalm 34:18 "The Lord is near to the broken-hearted" might at first glance be read as anyone who is grieving or suffered a loss. However in Derek Kidner's commentary on the Psalms he asserts that this "broken-heartedness" is referring to those who are broken over their sins.


What does this mean for us? Is this a theological lesson that these two forms of suffering are the only ones that matter? What about physical suffering not caused by sin or enemies? What about the death of a loved one? What about an unexpected job loss? It seems possible to read the testimony of the Psalms as teaching us that these things aren't really important.

I think that is a fairly generalised view but if it were wholly true (and I am not certain that it is) then, yes, that is a substantial outlook, that spiritual things are to be uppermost, whether inward spiritual experiences or whether outward spiritual conflicts. Otherwise, as the apostle Paul says I have learned in whatsoever situation I am, whether I am in want or whether I abound, therewith to be content. Or as Jesus told us  Martha, Martha, thou art troubled about many things. But one thing is needful.

Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help, below. as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 17,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Up-voted +1.

For those wondering whether this Q is on topic for C.SE, there are ways to improve this question into a better (more explicit) theological question, i.e. that after proper exegesis that OP has done the question becomes: how is a Christian theology justified in widening a particular person's suffering (David was a king but most of us aren't one) into any Christian's suffering while excluding certain worldly "suffering" seek by prosperity gospel (not enough honor / riches)?

Well, it would hardly be surprising if John Calvin got something wrong. Rather, I'd say that's the norm.

The Psalms give representative but not exhaustive examples. However, there are instances where the structure of one or more Psalms implies an induction from the parts to the whole. By this logic, it is conveyed that all times, all situations and all emotions are covered.
For example, in the poem in Ecclesiastes 3, Solomon lists 28 times of life. Are there other activities in life besides those? Yes, but the list that is given and the subsequent appeal to eternity intends to be taken as comprehensive.
Why speak of Ecclesiastes? If you study the themes of Psalms 1 to 28, you will find (with three deviations) a one to one correspondence in matching order between each psalm and a time from Solomon’s list. The deviations are in Psalms 1, 2 and 28. Those departures tell a story. Psalm 1 speaks of planting and uprooting, not a time to be born. One of the most prominent warnings the prophets gave to Israel was of the coming exile should they not repent, thus the swap. Psalm 2 then speaks of the birth of the Son, a prophecy of the Christ, who came after the exile. It also speaks of wrath and destruction, a time to die. Lastly, Psalm 28 includes themes from not one but thirteen times. This indicates the anarchy that attends Christ’s return, when all times will be fulfilled, then stop. (This summarizes analysis from my book Plague, Precept, Prophet, Peace.
The inference to be drawn is that the Psalms address every time of life.
In like fashion, there are seven psalms that speak of thunder. If you take them in ascending order by psalm number you can pair each with a passage in Revelation where thunder is mentioned. (You must exclude Revelation 10 which names the seven thunders.) Each such psalm has themes matching its passage in Revelation. For example:

The Lord announces the word, and the women who proclaim it are a
mighty throng: “Kings and armies flee in haste; the women at home
divide the plunder. (Psalm 68:11-12, NIV)
Then the kings of the earth, the princes, the generals, the rich, the
mighty, and everyone else, both slave and free, hid in caves and among
the rocks of the mountains. (Revelation 6:15, NIV)

An analysis of all seven thunder psalms may be found in my book Peace, like Solomon Never Knew in the chapter “Aftertaste: Donner and Blitzen”. The conclusion is that in matters of God’s wrath against evil and deliverance of his children, again the Psalms are comprehensive. (The chapter is available for free online here:  Voice of the Seven Thunders )
Elsewhere in my writing I address the seven Historical Psalms. They collectively form a seven part harvest pattern that lines up with Jesus’ temptation in the desert and the book of Job. That means that the Psalms are comprehensive in addressing how God carries a person suffering from every kind of distress (like Job) or facing every kind of temptation (like Jesus) from a place of barrenness to a place of abundant harvest.
The psalms come grouped in many such series, each calling forth a different aspect of God’s care for us and telling us that He will help us with all our troubles.
Addendum: Psalm 102
One need not wrangle long series of psalms into a structure to derive a useful answer to this question. Psalm 102, likely written by King Hezekiah or one of his men, provides a marvelous framework whereby the penitent catalogues his problems and then turns to the Lord for help with them all.
The early verses of the complaint can be diagrammed into a grid. The rows of the grid show which part of the person is affected, Mind, Body or Heart. Then the columns deal with four relationship crises, each with a cause and a symptom or result. The four are:

Isolation from God leads to Depression (v1-4)
Isolation from Society leads to Loneliness (v5-7)
Human Opposition leads to mourning (v8-9)
God’s Wrath leads to Guilt (v10-11)

Thus by the structure we see that the whole person is involved and all relationships affected either by being withdrawn or turned against the sufferer. A detailed analysis of Psalm 102 may be found here:
Psalm 102

An intriguing answer!

@Anne - I have spent lots of time over the last four years studying the Psalms. They are far more intriguing than anything I will ever be able to write!
